# C# Reading the registry: ProductID returns null in x86 targeted app. "Any CPU" works fine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry, 32bit-64bit

I have recently moved to a W7 64bit machine with VS 2010.
My project is set to run on `Any CPU`. When I change this to be targeted at `x86` I noticed some of my registry calls no longer work.

I am trying to read the `ProductID` field like so:

```
RegistryKey windowsNTKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
object productID = windowsNTKey.GetValue("ProductId");
```

`productID` is always `null` when running in x86 mode, when running in "Any CPU" it works correctly.  What is going on here?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOW64#Registry_and_file_system) - it's reading from a different area of the registry. I don't know what best way to work with this is, though.

Comment: @Rup - How do I get around it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some registry keys are redirected by WOW64. More information on this topic is available on MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx

If you really want to always access the x64 node (.Net4) :

```
  RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
  RegistryKey windowsNTKey = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
  object productID = windowsNTKey.GetValue("ProductId");
```

Comment: ` RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey` doesn't exist for me... I only have `RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey`? I am `using Microsoft.Win32;` so cannot understand why?

Comment: @Chris the only difference I can see between the two methods accessability is that the `OpenbaseKey` is not `ComVisible`

Comment: Using `OpenRemoteBaseKey` doesn't allow me to pass the `RegistryView` enum as an argument, do I need to reference a special Assembly?

Comment: Ahh... I'm targeting 3.5, these functions are only available in .NET 4

Answer (score 9):

This code will get the id for all kinds of os architectures and program architectures. Could be written shorter but I like the readability

```
    static string GetProductId()
    {
        RegistryKey localMachine = null;
        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
        {
            localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
        }
        else
        {
            localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
        }
        RegistryKey windowsNTKey = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
        return windowsNTKey.GetValue("ProductId").ToString();
    }
```

Comment: "If you request a 64-bit view on a 32-bit operating system, the returned keys will be in the 32-bit view." http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx

Answer (score 3):

On win64 some registry keys of 32-bit application are stored in `Software\Wow6432Node` subkey.

If you want to switch into 64 bit key you can use RegistryView enum as parameter of `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey`

Personally to make code working always in main registry key (not WoW6432) im using such construction:

`RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32)`